# Ansible 2.4.2 - Can I use delegate_to with password?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want execute a task from  my ansible role on another host. Can I do it with delegate_to or I should use other a way?

```
- name: Create user on remote host
  user:
    name: "{{ item.1 }}"
    state: present
  delegate_to: "user@{{ item.0.host }}"
  run_once: true
  become: True
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ user_ssh_keys_slave_hosts }}"
    - users
  when: item.1 is defined
```

Goal: I want create an user on remote host use login:password and ssh argument = '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'

For my inventory file I use next vars:

```
ansible_connection: ssh
ansible_user: user
ansible_ssh_pass: pass
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH gets configured by `~/.ssh/config`. There you can say which authentication type should be users. And there you should put your SSH options. This defines that the connection to a host should be made with a different user name:

```
Host item-0-host
  User user
  StrictHostKeyCecking no
  RSAAuthentication no
  HostName name-of-the-item-0-host
```

By this you have two host names. The original host name, you can use to manage the host itself. And a new host name, you can use to do the user management.

I am not sure but I think, you can not specify a user name in the value of the `delegate_to` option.

Btw: do you know the [user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_module.html) module of Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

Tnx for your answer. I resolved my question.

ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' in inventory file.

And

```
- name: Set authorized key on remote host
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.1 }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ user_ssh_public_key_fingerprint.stdout }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item.0.host }}"
  run_once: true
  become: True
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ user_ssh_keys_slave_hosts }}"
    - users
  when: item.1 is defined



user_ssh_keys_slave_group: "{{ groups['slave_hosts']|default([''])}}"
user_ssh_keys_slave_hosts: "{%- set ssh_user = [] %}{%- for host in user_ssh_keys_slave_group %}
                                {{- ssh_user.append(dict(host=host, ssh_user=hostvars[host]['slave_hosts']|default([]))) }}
                                {%- endfor %}
                                {{- ssh_user -}}"
```